# To prove a statement about finite groups of even order.

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is a group of even order then prove that there is an element $a$ in $G$ such that $a$ does not equal the identity element $e$ and $a^2=e$. 
I just know the fact that the order of element divides the order of group and $a^2=e$ for all $a$ belonging to $G$ is an abelian group. 
How can I prove the statement using these facts?  Even if theres another simple way to do this then it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a good strategy would be to consider that every element must have an inverse in $G,*$, where $*$ is the binary operation of the group. If you know the size of the group is $2n: n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, what can you say about the "pairing" of elements and their inverses?

(Hint: there are $2n-1$ elements not including the identity).

Comment: Yes, if i consider the pairing of elements with their inverses, then there always remains an element whose inverse is itself. That means this proof is enough.

Comment: Very nice strategy it is, i got it clear now.

Comment: I think a clean way to do it would be to use contradiction. Assume no element satisfies the criterion. That implies that every element and its inverse are distinct. This means there is a one-to-one correspondence between the two. But wait, how is it possible if the remaining elements have odd cardinality? Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Take a look at the set 
$$
A=\{g\in G| g^2\neq e\}
$$
Note that $e\not\in A$.